# ArangoDB - Format of csv files to import (using arangoimp) to greated undirected edges in graphs

Tags: arangodb

Format of csv files to import (using arangoimp) to greated undirected edges. I used "_to" and "_from" to import directed edges
(example:
timestamp   date    ID  _to      _from
1462750810  7/3/16  311 Media   Passengers
1457010729  1/3/17  343 Media   Passengers
1480483304  3/16/16 502 Media   Passengers
)
This created a graph that could be viewed from the Web Interface. But I can't query using INBOUND edges. So I want to convert my graph to an undirected graph to overcome this problem. Im unable to figure out the right CSV format for the same. 
It throws "**missing '_from' or '_to' attribute, offending document:**" error everytime I change the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create an undirected graph in ArangoDB, there only exists directed graphs.

It would be helpful if you post your query. Maybe there is something wrong with it. Have you tried OUTBOUND instead of INBOUND in your query?